# How to convert NSData of bytes to NSArray and print contents? Avoiding Javascript XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, objective-c, arrays, xmlhttprequest, nsarray

I have a binary file and I'm trying to put the contents into an array as is to simulate an XMLHTTPRequest which would read and return binary data. I already tried what the other posts similar to this had and this is the code I came up with. I'm not sure why I can't print out the array. A better way to get results similar to that of the function below would also be highly appreciated.

```
NSString *str0=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"exec" ofType:nil];
NSData* data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str0];
NSArray* array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data0];
NSUInteger len= [data0 length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data0 bytes], len);
NSLog(@"THIS IS THE exec %b",byteData);
```

I'm trying to achieve the same effect as this javascript would return in objective C:

```
function load_binary_resource(url) {
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', url, false);
req.overrideMimeType('text\/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
req.send(null);
if (req.status != 200) {
    document.write("fail downloading loader");
    stop = 1
};
return req.responseText;
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "binary data"? Is expected result string elements of an array, or an `ArrayBuffer`?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why I can't print out the array.

When you compiled your code did you read the warnings? The first warning you get tells you that `array` is unused. The second warning is the important one, for the line:

```
NSLog(@"THIS IS THE exec %b",byteData);
```

you get the warning:

```
Invalid conversion specifier 'b'
```

There is no `%b` format, which you where presumably guessing would be `Byte`. You need to read [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html). For there you will discover there is no format for a `Byte`, but `%02x` will format an integer as 2 hexadecimal digits with a leading zero if required. You can use this to output a `Byte`, e.g.:

```
Byte b = 0x42;
NSLog(@"b = %2x", b);
```

That will output a single `Byte` value, but there is no format to output an array of `Byte`s. For that you will have to write a suitable loop and output the `Byte`s one at a time, laid out as you choose (e.g. 8 per line, comma operated).

> I'm trying to achieve the same effect as this javascript would return in objective C

Well your code doesn't do that exactly, but it is close. Lines 1-2 read in the file as raw bytes and store them as an `NSData` value. While lines 4-6 produce a `malloc()`'ed C style array of bytes from that `NSData` value (which you must later `free()` or you'll have memory leak).

The JavaScript returns the raw bytes as a string without interpreting them according to any encoding (ASCII, UTF-8, etc.). Your `NSData` value contains those raw bytes as could be a suitable type to use in Objective-C. An `NSString` is not a good choice as it will interpret the bytes according to a character encoding. However your C style array of bytes would count as a C style string if you added a trailing `NULL` byte. Remember though if you are `malloc`'ing C arrays/strings you do need to `free()` them as well when no longer needed.

HTH

Comment: oh yes, I forgot to comment out the b but even taking out the b leads to "bad receiver type 'Byte' " how else can I print out the byte* byteData array and can I loop NSData object as I can an NSArray?

Comment: "Taking out the b" leaves no format specifier so of course you gat an error. Follow the answer to print out the C byte array. You can access the individual bytes in an `NSData`, read the docs for the methods available. You can create an `NSArray` if you wish but as they can only contain objects, not basic values, you will need to wrap each byte using `NSValue` or `NSNumber`. At a guess using an `NSArray` probably isn't your best choice, `NSData` is probably better.

Comment: well, I ended up creating a string of the hex values so basically now I have a string having the same hex bytes that my NSData had so now I'm going to try to loop through the string which divides the hex bytes by spaces and put each "string" into an array because this is suppose to work in conjunction with a piece of javascript that's expecting the same output as the original load_binary_resource. I don't think it would work if I gave it the NSData object right?

Comment: Superficially your process seems involved (file -> data -> string of hex character pairs -> array of 2 character hex character strings) and nothing like the JavaScript end result (string/sequence of byte values), but this is your design and you know what your final goal is. The keyword in this is *design*, you need a spec/goal, to design a solution, and to implement it. If the design/implementation doesn't work ask a new question, provide the details, show what you've done, explain the problem, etc. Someone will undoubtedly help you.

Comment: My main goal is to get the same results in an array as the javascript would return. I don't think I understand where the difference lies between the js reading of a file and the objective C. My attempt was trying to do the same in objective C and I don't think I got the same result if I understand your explanation correctly. I'm trying to fix it to be the same end result, almost like a translation.